# How to incorporate php mail with dynamic input values

Tags: jquery, html, css, php

on my site, I have a link in my nav bar that says 'refer a friend' using jquery a box pops up with two input boxes, one that is a place to enter the persons email in which you want to send a referral email and one box to enter in their name. I am looking for a good tutorial in how to get started about dynamically adding the values that are typed in, and sending them to the php mail on this same page. I am a newbie at php and some sort of guidance would be very helpful

thanks in advance

This is what I've come up with so far:

$

```
referral_email = $_POST['referral_email'];
$referral_name = $_POST['referral_name'];

if(isset($_POST['referral_form']) ) {



    $query = "SELECT * FROM `cysticUsers` WHERE `id` = '" . $prof->id . "'";
    $request = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($request); 

    $Email = $result['Email'];

        $to = $referral_email;
        $subject = "$auth->first_name $auth->last_name sent you an invitation to CysticLife.org";
        $message = "Hello $referral_name, $auth->first_name $auth->last_name sent you an invite to join CysticLife.org ";
        $from = "$auth->Email";
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
        $headers .= "From: $from";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }

?>
<div id="toggle_me">
        <div id="refer_title">
            Invite a friend
            <a id="nevermind" href="#">nevermind</a>
        </div>
    <form name="refer_email" method="post" action="#">
        <table id="refer_house">
            <tr>
                <td class="refer_left">
                    To:
                </td>
                <td class="refer_right">
                <input type="text" name="to_email" value="Enter Recipient's E-Mail Address<?php $_POST['referral_email'];?>" class="defaulted"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="refer_right">
                </td>
                <td class="refer_right">
                    <input type="text" name="to_name" value="Enter Recipient's Name<?php $_POST['referral_name'];?>" class="defaulted"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="refer_submit">
            <input type="submit" name="referral_form" value="Send" />
        </div>
```

Comment: Some of your existing code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple form would be:

referFriend.php:

```
<?php

    $referralEmail = $_REQUEST['referralEmail'];
    $referralName = $_REQUEST['referralName'];

    $msgSubject = "Hey $referralName, Bob recommends you check this out!";
    $msgBody = "$referralName,

    Check this out: http://www.google.com

    Your friend,
    Bob";

    mail($referralEmail, $msgSubject, $msgBody);

?>
```

Assuming you are sending 'referralEmail' and 'referralName' from the jQuery script.  You'll also need to plug in the referrer's name in place of 'Bob.'

Additionally you should be validating the data as well as using $_GET or $_POST (as opposed to $_REQUEST) depending on how you're sending the variables.

You could test that using:

http://www.**your-domain**.com/referFriend.php?referralEmail=**test@test.com**&referralName=**Chad**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this asynchronously (without a page load) you'll have to send the contents of the input to another PHP page via AJAX. Otherwise you should be able to just use a 's build in submit and catch the contents at the top of the page.

If you're interested in doing it asynchronously you can take a look at jQuery's .ajax, .post or .get functions. Let us know if you have more questions about these functions.

Comment: I usually use .post to keep the URL clean and empty haha.